# Having to chmod my samba shares to 0777 feels wrong just to get them to be writeable. Is this really necessary?

Tags: samba

Since setting up my samba shares I have been unable to write to either of them. My config:

```
[minecraft]
        path = /opt/minecraft
        writeable = yes
        browseable = yes
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes
        create mask = 0777

[www]
        path = /var/www
        writeable = yes
        read only = no
        browseable = yes
        guest ok = yes
        create mask = 0777
```

I am unable however to write to either of these shares from a Windows machine. I have the folders themselves (and all subfolders) at 755, but still nothing.

The only thing that has allowed me to get the shares to be writeable is making them and their subfolders 777 and that just feels wrong.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried forcing the user to be the one that owns the directory? `force user = [owner]`? Probably not elegant but it seems to work. You might be able to do it via a group as well, but I quit experimenting once I got it to work.

Comment: I'll test that out. I should have kept track of this, but what *should* the permissions of files/folders be. I just changed both folders recursively to 777 because I needed it to work...

Comment: Looks like mine are 750. I have force user = the owner and force group = the owner's group. I also have a valid users = [] [] listing the people allowed to access it.  This seems to let the people in the valid users line access the directory but everything they do is as if they were the owner.

Comment: Perhaps my `pathlld` tool might help. https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?".

Comment: Your force user and force group parameters did the trick. Make it an actual answer and I'll select it. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, I just came back to this. Your answer is fine, remember to come back and accept it. I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: I can't even accept mine yet. If you write an answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being to add `force user = www-data`